# Java: how to store references to all instances of a class?

Tags: java, static, garbage-collection

I'm more used to C++. To get a list of all instances of a class (this is a library class that can be extended by the user), I usually have a static container with all references to such objects:

```
#include <list>
class CPPClass;

class CPPClass {
   public:
   CPPClass() {
      objList.push_back(this);
   }
   ~CPPClass() {
      objList.remove(this);
   }

   private:
   static std::list<CPPClass *> objList;
};

std::list<CPPClass *> CPPClass::objList;
```

How should I do the same in Java? I have a few concerns:

- someone mentioned to me that there can be multiple classloaders, and that might cause problems
- there is no destructor in java, so how would the references be removed from the list?
- if the references are not removed, when do these objects get garbage-collected?

Comment: Store [Weak References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to the object to allow them to get garbage collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy things first: multiple classloaders won't cause you a problem unless you use a non-standard delegation pattern (with a custom classloader). If you do have such a non-standard classloader, you can get a situation wheredifferent parts of the app are using different versions of the `CPPClass` class (each version from a different ClassLoader). This has various issues (you can get a `ClassCastException` casting from `CPPClass` to `CPPClass`!), but it shouldn't affect your static collection; each `CPPClass` will just have its own, separate collection.

Next thing: don't add the objects to the collection from the constructor. Leaking the `this` reference from a constructor can lead to memory model problems. Instead, you should create a static factory method that creates the object and then separately adds it to the static collection. That collection should also be thread-safe, of course.

Finally, the core question. If each object is not equal to any other object (that is, if you haven't overridden `Object.equals`), you could use a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html), with the objects as keys. If the class does override `equals`, you can create a collection of [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)s, which you can prune at convenient times (on insert, on retrieving the list, etc.). A WeakReference will not prevent the object it refers to from being GCed -- it'll just return `null` from `get` after that GC has happened.

But if I may editorialize a bit, "solutions" like this often hint at an ill-defined object lifecycle, which has other maintainability issues. It could be better if your objects implement `Closeable` or have a similar way for the code that uses them to declare that it's finished with them.

Comment: I guess I can't rely on the `equals` method not being overridden, since the user may do whatever they want... unless maybe I make it final, but I suppose that would be too restrictive... Besides, what would I put in the value of the `WeakHashMap`? So, I think I'm left with either something like a `WeakArrayList` (is there such a thing?) or implementing the container (I guess in Java it's called collection?) myself. Implementing `Closeable`, though, seems like going back to a nice and familiar way of programming, but would that be the ideal Java solution?

Comment: Implementing Closeable (or AutoCloseable if you're on Java 1.7 and want to use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) is definitely idiomatic Java. Lots of JDK classes do that -- InputStream, JDBC classes, etc. If you did want to use your own collection, I would start at a `List<WeakReference<CPPClass>>`. I wouldn't implement my own collection from scratch, just use a JDK collection and manually go through it to purge stale WeakReferences.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing a reference to an object, store a [WeakReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to the object - this way the garbage collector will free the object if the WeakReference is the only reference that remains.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed make the list static, just make sure you also initialise it properly.

```
List<CPPClass> objlist;
static {
    objlist = new List<CPPClass>();
}
```

Or something similar should do that.

If you do not remove the reference, it will never get garbage collected because the garbage collector will assume the object is still in use.

There is something that seems a bit like a destructor: the method `finalize`. But because this method is only called by the garbage collector and you can not use it yourself, it will be of no use to you.